# how to redirect 301 in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

how to 301 redirect using .htaccess file in wordpress.

```
www.mysite.com/about.html/page1
www.mysite.com/about.html/page2
www.mysite.com/about.html/page3
www.mysite.com/about.html/page(anypage)
```

redirect to

```
 www.mysite.com/
```

how can i do redirect like this.

below redirection not working for me

```
Redirect 301 about.html/ /
```

result is `www.mysite.com//page1` this is wrong. i want to redirect whole url to my home page.

Comment: I think you need to set the rewritebase and than something like `Redirect 301 ^about.hrml.*$ /`

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
RewriteRule ^about\.hrml(.*)$ http://www.example.com/ [R=301,L]
```

Pattern matches anything beginning with `about.hrml` (Note the `.` before `hrml` is escaped since it's a regular expression and `.` means any non-newline character). Redirects to your website (Replace http://www.example.com) with your own URL. `R=301` tells the server to use 301 code and `L` means this should be the last rule.

Comment: Hi , @jonathon 
can you help me for this.sorry , i am typing **html as hrml**

i have added below code in my htaccess . can you check my code

Comment: `# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
RewriteRule ^about-us\.html$ http://www.example.com/ [R=301,L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress`